# How can I GET request, wait for data using socket and send a response back?

Tags: javascript, express, socket.io

I have tried to google this question and frankly speaking I found loads of answers. But the problem is that I get too many options and I am already lost. I am not a web developer but I have to do this small thing in order to go further, so your help will be appreciated.

Consider that I have a web server written in expressjs and one of the routers is called goal. Whenever a user sends a GET request to my router (something like: https://www.myserver.com/goal) I need to create a client socket, connect with that socket to another server (another server is https://www.secondserver.com/goal) with no specific port, wait for the data, close the socket and send the data back to the original user.

How can I do it?

I have started with this simple code, which handles the basic GET request:

```
router.get("/", (req,res,next)=>{
    // need to create a socket
    // then it should invoke something like io.connect, I am not sure
     // Listen until I get the JSON data
    .then(docs => {
        const response = {
            // Modify the received JSON data from second server
                }
            })
        }
        res.status(200).json(response);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.status(500).json({
            message: "error",
            error : err
        });
    });
});
```